# Rendering html5 video on iPad crashes

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-video

I have an app that runs in Web view. But when I render some videos and click the play button, the app crashes. This happens with some videos, not all. What I want is to try to catch any exception occurring and then load a static image if an exception occurs.

I am coding in JavaScript and would highly appreciate if anyone can guide me on how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: if there is a crash (app exist unexpectedly), you cannot catch it using JS as it is at a lower level...

Comment: In that case what is the correct way to have html5 video on ipad. ? Or need to create the video file itself in specific format / size etc

Comment: I think you can use any format supported by iOS Safari like [MPEG-4/H.264](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4). But however your app shouldn't crash because of a video in an invalid format.